# python - importing modules on shared server

Tags: python, shared, imaplib

i have a script named gmailCleaner.py, on my pc it runs great and ajusts my gmail (using imap) just the way i want.

so i wanted to make this script availabl to everybody on my website (shared hosting, python enabled) the script runs but fails to connect to gmail (using same settings as in my pc, only diffrence is that on pc i use raw_input and on the server i use fata from html form)

i assumed it was because they lack the imaplib file i was using - so i uploaded it to the server (same folder as the script) it didnt work.

**new: getting this error: 'module' object has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'**

any kind of help will be good

the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import imaplib
import os
import cgi

print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'

try:
    M=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
except:
    print 'cannot connect to gmail<br />'
```

and it fails :S
it prints the 'cannot connect to gmail' means it runs.

edit for comment, not yet the most user friendly code ever, just wanted it to work first (deleting all emails from pesific sender):

```
try:    
    USER = form.getvalue('username')
    PASS = form.getvalue('password')
    SENDER = form.getvalue('from')
    print USER
except:
    print 'cannot get form info<br />'

try:
    M=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
    M.login(USER +'@gmail.com',PASS)
    status, count = M.select('Inbox')
except Exception as e: print e

try:
    SENDER = '\"' + SENDER + '\"'
    data = M.search(None, 'FROM', SENDER)
    a = str(data[1])
    a = a.split()
    b = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(a[-1]) - 2:
        b = b + a[-1][i]
        i += 1
    a[-1] = b
    b = ''
    i = 2
    while i < len(a[0]):
        b = b + a[0][i]
        i += 1
    a[0] = b
except:
    print 'cannot get ids<br />'


try:
    print 'deleting!<br />'
    i = 0
    while i < len(a):
        M.store(a[i], '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
        i += 1
except:
    print 'cannot delete<br />'
```

Comment: You need to actually catch the error and print it. something like `except Exception as e: print e`

Comment: I am more interested to see your source code :)

Comment: i swapped my except with the line u provided @agf    except Exception as e: print e    and now it gives me 404 error when i try to call it (when i remove that line it still finds the script)

Comment: @kracekumar i submitted i, what do u want to see?

Comment: @galtzhayek : was interested to see how you connect to gmail and perform all the operations.

Comment: @kracekumar ok i edited and posted some :)

Comment: @agf ok i got it to show an error messege.

Answer (score 0):

If your shared server supports pip install and virtualenv, try this
`virtualenv env --no-site-packages`
`pip install python<version>`
`pip install otherpythonpackages`

This should solve your problem.

Comment: i dont know what pip install and virtualenv are (googled it and read a bit) but they dont let me have any installing access so i assume i cant do that...

Comment: `pip` is used for installing python packages, `virtualenv` is used to execute python program in a env where you can have all your dependencies, by this way, different users can use different version and libraries without being installed system wide.

Comment: so i should just run these 3 lines as python script?